# How to get the Row Number from the Target During A Worksheet_Change Event?

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following bit of code that detects that a cell value has changed. I want to know which row the cell belongs to.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range

    ' The variable KeyCells contains the cells that will
    ' cause an alert when they are changed.

    Set KeyCells = Range("F2:F20")

    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
           Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Last Contact Date " & Target.Address & " has changed."
        Set Row_number = ???????

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: `Target.Row` and `Target.Column`.

Comment: Don't forget Target can be more than a single cell

Comment: That's a good point @TimWilliams. I'll update my answer so that the two people that view it in the next decade will be all the wiser!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range

    ' The variable KeyCells contains the cells that will
    ' cause an alert when they are changed.

    Set KeyCells = Range("F2:F20")

    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
           Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Last Contact Date Row: " & Target.Row & " Column: " & Target.Column & " has changed."
        'Set Row_number = ???????

    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be pulled from the [Target variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change) that is a [range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.range) that you can pull lots of information from, including the Row. In your case, it would look like this:

**UPDATED** to defend against possibility of user having more than one row. A couple suggestions for what to do.

```
If Target.Rows.Count > 1 Then
    'do nothing

    'or
    MsgBox "You messed up by selecting " & Target.Rows.Count & " rows!!!", _
    vbCritical, "Come on!"

    'or
    Row_Number = Target.Cells(1, 1).Row 'this will return the top row selection


Else
    'when one row
    Row_Number = Target.Row

End If
```